# Linux-Headers for Different Kernel Version than installed

Tags: module, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How can you get the Linux-Headers for a different Kernel Version than the one installed on the system?(Debian) I searched the whole Web and couldn't find anything other than that you can download the Headers for you current running kernel, why is it so hard to get the Headers for a non running kernel?

I need the 4.16 headers to compile a LKM, but im running on 4.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the kernel headers and source for any of the standard releases from:

> git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux

Or from: https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/

If pulling from the git repo, you will need to checkout the specific version you wish to build for. In your case:

> git checkout v4.16