# Installing different version Linux-Headers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-kernel-headers

My kernel version is 4.9.0-12-amd64 but I cannot find it's headers.

Could I install the **linux-headers-4.9.0-13-amd64** instead?

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628640/linux-headers-for-different-kernel-version-than-installed) to this but the answer is not what I want to know (or I think so)

Comment: Sure you can install it, but it won't be much use unless you have a matching kernel.

Comment: It depends on the use. API doesn't change much, so it may be OK, but if you need more (ABI), you may need the exact configuration.

Comment: Where di you get the kernel?

Comment: It's a server I started working on recently. It was created a long time ago and I don't want to mess up anything.